# animate2D in gnuplot

Tags: animation, gnuplot

I have in file='Circle.dat' the following 5 columns which correspond to t,x,y,v_x,v_y

```
           0.00000000       1.50000000       1.00000000      -0.00000000      0.500000000
           9.99999978E-03   1.49997497       1.00499988      -4.99991653E-03  0.499974996
           1.99999996E-02   1.49989998       1.00999928      -9.99933295E-03  0.499900013
           2.99999993E-02   1.49977505       1.01499772      -1.49977496E-02  0.499775022
...
```

How can use gnuplot to make 2D animation based on the followings

```
gnuplot> file = ”Circle.dat”
gnuplot> set xrange [0:1.6]; set yrange [0:1.6]
gnuplot> t0 = 0; tf = 20 ; dt = 0.1
gnuplot> load ”animate2D.gnu”
```

Comment: Do you want to animate in real time on the screen, or to create an animated gif file for later display?

Comment: would prefer to create an animated gif